# How can I thank someone for an edit, a protect etc?

Tags: discussion

I can thank someone for a great answer or question by upvoting, is there some way to thank someone for an edit or for protecting a question?

Comment: "Thanks for the edit!"

Comment: ^ Like that, in a comment.

Comment: It doesn't seem like enough!

Comment: Well, you can always mail me a fiver. :3

Comment: @Keen Ugh, I hate that. It's noise, both for the recipient (go to inbox, oh no, it's nothing important after all) and for the community (a comment, I'll read it… Nope, nothing in it for me).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Gilles Except that (as long as thanking users is not a common event) it can show recognition of a particularly good edit, like what [neilfein recently did on an older answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10015/2242), and encourage more of those.

Comment: @Izkata yeah, when someone goes above and beyond I'd like to give them a +1.

Comment: @Gilles interesting.  My comments were deleted, yet the chit-chat already in the comments thread stays?  My link to the blog entry is entirely relevant, even if I tend towards agreeing with you that "thanks for the edit" is mostly unwanted "noise". Or is there some other reason my comments were deleted?

Comment: @Beofett Your comment seemed to be solely intended for me and not for general discussion. If you wanted to make a point with your link, I suggest doing so more clearly, in an answer.

Comment: @Gilles I can point to several other comments right here on the page that fit that description precisely.  If you're going to be so quick to "clean up" comments, you really ought to make an effort to be consistent.  Otherwise, it comes off as arbitrary censorship.

Comment: @Beofett Cool it off with the insults, please. I've already pinged the other moderators on the site to look at the comments here.

Comment: @Gilles What insults? All I said was that it comes off poorly.  That's not an insult; it is merely feedback.

Comment: @Beofett & Gilles Deleting those comments seems fine to me.  Comments are pretty limited by their nature, so it was unclear if that was a message for Gilles specifically, or a comment for the general community.  All comments are [expected to be potentially deleted](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment), so accusing someone who deletes comments as partaking in "censorship" is a bit much.

Comment: @Keen if it was unclear if the comment was for the general community, or Gilles specifically, doesn't it seem like the correct course of action would be to ask for clarification, instead of just arbitrarily deleting it without contacting the poster? I know comments are expected to be potentially deleted, but how is my comment less useful than "well, you can always mail me a fiver"? Also, both you and Gilles need to reread my comment. I never insulted him, or "accused" him of partaking in censorship. I said that it could *appear* to be rather arbitrary censorship.

Comment: Incidentally, you both seem to be finding the term "censorship" inherently offensive.  Censorship is merely the removal of content that is deemed offensive or otherwise inappropriate.  It is, in fact, part of a moderator's job to censor content that needs to be removed. Calling removal of content "censorship" is a non-judgmental term. The only part of my comment that could be cause for concern is the "arbitrary" part, but neither you nor Gilles seem to have found that to be an objectionable term.

Comment: @Beofett  If a comment is simply a personal message to someone else in the discussion, then it becomes obsolete (i.e. a comment flag reason) once the recipient reads the message. Also, [censorhip](http://gilc.org/speech/osistudy/censorship/) definitely has a pejorative connotation, it's nowhere near a neutral term.  It usually refers to *abusing power* to remove things that have been deemed unacceptable by those in power.  Personally, my feelings on the word 'arbitrary' have been desensitized over months of being told various actions I took while moderating were "arbitrary". ;)

Comment: @Keen from the article you linked (right near the top): "Not all censorship is equal, nor does all arise from government or external force. People self-censor all the time; such restraint can be part of the price of rational dialogue."  Like many other terms, some people leap on the negative connotations, while never being aware of the non-negative (or even positive).  However, if you feel "deletion" is somehow preferable to "censorship", please feel free to edit my comment (as I cannot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is:

- **If it is to simply make the person feel better/appreciated**, you can thank them on chat - I agree with Gilles's comment above that a "Thank you" comment is just noise.
- **If you wish to do it as an act of positive reinforcement**, as Keen said, there likely isn't any need to use your thanking upvote as direct reward feedback anymore for this kind of user.
- **If it is a wish to grant them a more "material" benefit than a mere good word**, you can always seek out an older post by that user which seems quality enough to deserve an upvote but you didn't upvote before (may be a tag you don't follow closely).

  Just make sure not to upvote any random post that doesn't deserve upvotes - but for a kind of user who would provide this helpful edit, I'd wager it's not very hard to find a good post of theirs that deserves it.

  It will not be clearly associated with your expressing thanks to them communications wise (unless you also comment on chat), but an anonymous gift is (sometimes|often) better than named one; and see the last bullet point re: no need for positive reinforcement.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking to specifically reward someone for an edit or protect?  That's not really feasible.  The system does reward low-rep users who submit accepted edits, but that doesn't sound like what you're looking for.  The system isn't built to reward more abstract actions people can take to contribute to the site.

By the time you have the rep to protect or edit questions, you're already a pretty devoted member of the community, so it's assumed that your use of those abilities doesn't require a reward mechanism.