# What is the correct way to thank an editor?

Tags: discussion, editing

I'm French.

While I consider myself fully bilingual in comprehension (reading/listening), I'm less good with production (writing/speaking), especially with grammar (due to bad learning process).

When I see edits on my questions, I'm frequently appalled at what I wrote, and feel like a kid with a bad grade. I frequently would like to thank the editor for taking the time to improve my message.

Is it 'allowed', and what is the correct process for it?

Comment: Asked in 2012: [How can I thank someone for an edit, a protect etc?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2103/31394)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Post a comment under your (edited) question that says

> Thank you @Whoever for your kind edit.

Note that 'thank you' comments are considered low-value, so don't be too alarmed if they eventually get washed away.

Answer (score 7):

You could always stop by chat. The editor may be active in a room where pretty much any discussion is allowed (and therefore can be pinged), or you could just drop by the [main SFF chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/58631) and say that you think they did a good job without notifying them (I've done that when I see new users who really take the time to improve their own questions, for example).

Now, I don't know how I would feel about being tracked down in chat for *other matters*, but I think most users would welcome some positivity like this.

Comment: Not to mention that some human posts in chat would make a nice difference from the endless stream of Marvin/Slarti/Smokey/etc. bot posts...

Comment: @DavidW I ignore Marvin, which makes for a much more pleasant chat experience, and the only downside is potentially pissing off the robots when they do gain sentience.

Comment: It's Marvin, he'd be pissed off anyway.  The saving grace is that he'd also be too depressed to do anything about it. :D

Comment: @DavidW And unless he breaks out of chat, I also won't be seeing his rants in chat on account of him being blocked.

Comment: But what if the editor doesn't visit chat?